# java stream List<Object[]> to Map<Object, List<Object[]>>

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have `List<Object[]>` inner join **MySQL query**, I need to create a **map** key **id** and value **object**.

The Code below works, but how to do it best with **Streams**?

```
Map<Object, List<Object[]>> convert(List<Object[]> objects) {
    Map<Object, List<Object[]>> objectListMap = objects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj[0], obj -> {
            List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(obj);
            return list;
        }, (obj1, obj2) -> {
            obj1.addAll(obj2);
            return obj1;
        }));
    return objectListMap;
}


Object[] objects structure:
objects[0] = person id
...
objects[10] = event id
...
objects[15] = event name
```

This query found all the person with the event visited, but the index in the objects array from 0 to 10 may be the same, 11-15 always change.

And I want to merge all object-lists that have the same id (objects[0]).

next for each value in 
      Map > 
convert to POJO:

```
PersonWithEvent converToEntity(List<Object[]> objects) {
Optional< PersonWithEvent > personWithEvent =                     
objects.stream()
.findFirst().map(obj -> {
    PersonWithEvent p = new PersonWithEvent();
    p.setId((Integer) obj[0]);
    ...
    return p;
});
personWithEvent.ifPresent(p -> {
    List<PersonEvent> personEvents = objects.stream()
            .map(obj -> {
                PersonEvent pe = new PersonEvent();
                pe.setName((String) obj[2]);
                ...
                return pe;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    p.setPersonEvents(personEvents);
 });
 return personWithEvent.get();
```

And Is it possible to do it for one stream?

Comment: Can you explain the desired structure a bit? It's not that easy to tell from your code. How do you plan to convert the `List<Object[]>`? What are the keys and what the values for the map? What is the `merge` function supposed to do?

Comment: Am I correct that each `Object[]` array has an **id** at index `0` and you want to map this id to the rest whole array like `objects[0] => objects`. And additionally you want to merge all object-lists that have the same **id** (`objects[0]`).

Comment: yes, And I want to merge all object-lists that have the same id (objects[0]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to group by element at index zero of an array `Object`

`Collectors.groupingBy` groups by the key

```
Map<Object, List<Object[]>> map = objects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0]));
```

with null and empty checks

```
Map<Object, List<Object[]>> map = objects.stream()
    .filter(o -> o != null && o.length != 0)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0]));
```

Example

```
List<Object[]> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new Object[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
objects.add(new Object[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
objects.add(new Object[] { 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
objects.add(new Object[] { 0, 6, 7, 8, 9 });

Map<Object, List<Object[]>> map = objects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0]));

System.out.println(map);
```

output is like

```
{
    0 = [[Ljava.lang.Object;@378bf509,
            [Ljava.lang.Object;@5fd0d5ae],
    1 = [[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d98a335],
    2 = [[Ljava.lang.Object;@16b98e56]
}
```

you can see `0` has two `List<Object[]>` values grouped by

Comment: `Collectors#groupingBy` is actually a nice and clean approach. Never worked with it before but it seems worth to learn.

Comment: You may consider using the filter `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` for removing `null` values. Just in case you didn't know that method.

Comment: @Zabuza yes but we need to filter empty arrays as well right here

Comment: @alex please vote and accept this answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

I would make the whole procedure more explicit and clean. Using a mixed-style with lots of comments and good variable names.

This should help a lot when it comes down to reading, understanding and maintaining your code.

```
Map<Object, List<Object[]>> convert(List<Object[]> entities) {
    Map<Object, List<Object[]>> idToEntitesWithSameId = new HashMap<>();

    entities.forEach(entity -> {
        // Create an entry for each entity,
        // merge with entities of same id
        Object id = entity[0];

        // Get current value or empty list
        List<Object[]> entitiesWithId = idToEntitesWithSameId
            .computeIfAbsent(id, ArrayList::new);

        // Add own entity, merge with other
        // entities of same id
        Arrays.stream(entity).forEach(entitiesWithId::add);
    });

    return idToEntitesWithSameId;
}
```